# incompatible types error when using switch case

Tags: java, switch-statement

Hi I'm making a program that should take a letter grade and convert it to a GPA value. The first part of the program took a percentage and converted that to a letter grade, and now I'm trying to convert that converted letter grade into a int value. We're only allowed to use switch case. However, when doing this I'm getting an incompatible types error     found   : java.lang.String required: int. Not sure on what I need to change, any help?

Thanks

```
  public static int convertToGradePoint(String letterGrade) {

  int gradepoint;

   switch (letterGrade) {

   case "A+" :
   gradepoint = 12;
   break;

   case "A" :
   gradepoint = 11;
   break;

   case "A-" :
   gradepoint = 10;
   break;

   case "B+" :
   gradepoint = 9;
   break;

   case "B" :
   gradepoint = 8;
   break;

   case "B-" :
   gradepoint = 7;
   break;

   case "C+" :
   gradepoint = 6;
   break;

   case "C" :
   gradepoint = 5;
   break;

   case "C-" :
   gradepoint = 4;
   break;

   case "D+" :
   gradepoint = 3;
   break;

   case "D" :
   gradepoint = 2;
   break;

   case "D-" :
   gradepoint = 1;
   break;

   default :
   gradepoint = 0;
   break;
 }

 return gradepoint;


  }
   }
```

Comment: Which version of Java you are using???

Comment: Why not throw all the letter grades and their `gradepoint` values into a `Map<String, Int>` and skip the `switch` entirely?

Comment: Perhaps get rid of the last curly bracket.

Answer (score 0):

You did not post enough code. You are probably doing this below:

```
String a = convertToGradePoint(input);
```

You need to do this:

```
int a = convertToGradePoint(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

> In Java SE 7 and later, you can use a `String` object in the switch
>   statement's expression

That means, your JDK version is < 7. You can get the latest version of JDK to compile the same code.

Comment: any idea on how I can get it to run on Dr Java. I'm running Java 8 on my computer, but Dr Java is only running JDK 6, and I have no clue on how to update it.

Comment: @JVAN, probably check you `PATH` variable and see if it is using `java 6` path.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot switch over a String instance, only int (and byte/char/short, but not long/double), unless you have Java7+.

alternative for this is to use if as following

```
if(letterGrade.equals("A+")){
 gradepoint = 12;
}
```

or upgrade your Java